# LVM -spread linux system over two physical disks?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, lvm

Two identical SSD disks of 4 TB.

Linux Mint installed on first disk, with 3 partitions being automatically created during fresh installation:

- /dev/sda1 BIOS Boot;
- /dev/sda2 EFI System mounted on  /boot/efi;
- /dev/sda3 Linux LVM i.e. LVM2 Physical Volume (LVM2 001).

Second disk /dev/sdb1 Linux LVM i.e. LVM2 Physical Volume (LVM2 001).

Eventually, I merged LVM volume groups, so that all logical volumes are now part of vgmint volume group.
Volumes:

- /dev/vgmint/root --->from disk1
- /dev/vgmint/swap_1 ---> from disk1
- /dev/vgmint/volume ---> from disk2

What I want to do now is to merge /dev/vgmint/volume into /dev/vgmint/root so that /dev/vgmint/root remains only, taking full available space from both disks.

Is this possible and how?

I want /dev/vgmint/volume to dissapear and its space being merged into /dev/vgmint/root.

In other words, I want to completely utilize both physical disks as one disk, I don't want separate mounted folders, but rather extend the Linux system folders over both SSD disks. How to accomplish that?

If this is not possible on existing system, is there a way to do it by fresh linux system install, can it be installed over 2 physical disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The steps are:

1. backup files from volume `/dev/vgmint/volume`
2. unmount it `umount /dev/vgmint/volume`
3. remove logical volume `lvremove /dev/vgmint/volume`
4. extend the volume and filesystem `lvextend --resizefs -L+100%FREE /dev/vgmint/root`
5. restore backuped files (if any)

P.S. I am not sure if the last command will work with `xfs`. If not you should (for point 4) first execute `lvextend -L+100%FREE /dev/vgmint/root` and then `xfs_grow /dev/vgmint/root`

Comment: Re works with xfs: I sure hope it does, it's exactly how I deal with my xfs lvs. (So, yes, it does work.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thank you for the update. Was not sure. Usually I first extend the volume and then (by hand) extend the filesystem :)

Comment: Is it lvresize or lvextend?

Comment: @zlatko, my mistake, should be `lvextend`. Will edit the answer :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov perfect, it works!!! Thank you very much! Only thing is that it seems it should be "-l" instead "-L", otherwise I get following error: "Can't parse size argument. Invalid argument for --size: +100%FREE. Error during parsing of command line."

Comment: @zlatko, this is strange. By manual and my experience it should be capital `L`

Comment: One is used for sizes in terms of LVM extents, the other for canonical data units. I always forget which is which.